# Please explain how google analytics would interpret IP addresses for a internal IP address range

Tags: networking, google-analytics

- A: represents my companies network  IP address range (10.90.10.0-255) INTERNAL IP addresses
- B: represents the larger organization that provides our network services (Not our ISP however)
- C: Represents our website that has google analytics installed.

When I access the site will google analytics record the 10.90... IP address?  Or will it only know of the external IP address that B pipes all traffic out thru?  234.255.255.000?

I really may not understand some basic concepts, but according to google this is possible.
https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55481&hl=en_US&utm_id=ad

But I agree with this forum.  If it is not routable google will never know about it.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=79087fbe4c6ade7b&hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to believe that Google Analytics tracks the IP address that makes a request to Google's servers; thus, they would only see the external IP.

Comment: Yes, that is my thought as well.  Too bad google seems to contradict that.

Comment: I'm guessing they used those addresses as examples to demonstrate how their regex works, not because they can actually track them. They should have used addresses from RFC 5737: "IPv4 Address Blocks Reserved for Documentation"

Comment: Whatever IP address sites like this see: http://www.whatsmyip.org/ is what Google Analytics sees. Chances are that that's B.